# Menu dropdown Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

when i run this with the big screen, its looks like this:
[Dropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEnmf.png)

. I want to open the dropdown under my Link menu:

this is how it looks with the small screen: [Dropdown Menu2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vFfq.png).

How I fix this with bootstrap? This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../assets/logo.png" alt="" width="100px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>

          <li class="active">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Link<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: It's not a proper code. You don't have `<div class="dropdown">`. See docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/#single-button and this one https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#supported-content

Answer (score 0):

[image: DropDown]

This works perfectly for me. Just wondering if you have installed the bootstrap package and included it in your angular.json file.

[image: Angular.Json]